# using lodash to generate a dynamic table in nested object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have got nested object containing students' details as below:

```
data = [
            {
                name: 'Gill, Jack',
                subjects: [
                    {
                        name: 'Mathematics',
                        scores: [
                            {
                                year: 7,
                                collection: 1,
                                score: 430,

                            },
                            {
                                year: 7,
                                collection: 2,
                                score: 500,

                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

}
I am going to generate a dynamic table in a webpage to show the last year's mark for each student. But unfortunately it is not working and prints N/A and I think there is something wrong with lodash as I am very new to it. I used an static array instead of scoreATL and the table had correct cell contents.

```
//Getting students ID from url
$.get('/rest/report/' + upn, function (data) {
...
data.subjects.forEach(function (subject) {

                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + subject.name + '</td>';
                for (var j = 0; j < data.cycleNumber; ++j) {


                    var scoreATL = _.findWhere(subject.scores, { year: data.yearForATL, collection: j });

                    if (scoreATL.score)
                        html += '<td>' + scoreATL.score + '</td>';
                    else
                        html += '<td>' + 'N/A' + '</td>';
                }
                html += "</tr>";
            });
...
}
```

I also tried this approach as well and shows N/A in all cells:

```
data.subjects.forEach(function (subject) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + subject.name + '</td>';
                for (var j = 0; j < data.cycleNumber; ++j) {

                    var scoreATL = 0;
                    scoreATL = _.result(_.findWhere(subject.scores, { year: data.yearForATL, collection: j }), score);

                    if (scoreATL)
                        html += '<td>' + scoreATL + '</td>';
                    else
                        html += '<td>' + 'N/A' + '</td>';
                }
                html += "</tr>";
            });
```

Comment: For a start `data` is an array so you should access `subjects` like so: `data[0].subjects.forEach`.

Comment: Define _not working_ and _failed_...

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, what is ````data.yearForATL```` ? What is ````data.cycleNumber````? Maybe you can post a final result. Also, if something works for you with native commands and is not too verbose you might want to consider leaving that so that you don't create extra dependencies.

Comment: You're still iterating over `data.subjects`, according to your sample, `data` is an array...